# setContentView and findViewById error

Tags: android

I am trying to move an application from android from an activity to a fragment mistake and I jump right on the part of
setContentView and in the findViewById and no longer do that and I tried everything even my basic level of androids allows me

```
public class Tactica extends Fragment {
    private ImageView cuadrado;
    private int modificarX = 100;
    private int modificarY = 100;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.tactica);
          cuadrado = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          cuadrado.setOnTouchListener(handlerMover);
          View tactics = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tactica, container, false);
          return tactics;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Is there any error message encountered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```
@Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
          View tactics = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tactica, container, false);
           cuadrado = (ImageView)tactics.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          cuadrado.setOnTouchListener(handlerMover);
          return tactics;
    }
```

Here you dont have to use this two lines in onCreateView Method

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tactica);
```

And you have to initialize imageview control after inflating the file and not before

Answer (score 4):

You should retrieve the ID from the contentView by inflating the contentView. When you are working with fragments. You do this as follows:

```
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tactica, container, false);
```

That way you can find Id's like this:

```
contentView.findViewById
```